# Get repeated path comparing 2 paths using c#

Tags: file, c#-4.0

I have 2 file-paths.

eg:

**Path 1** `C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\File1.info`

**Path 2** `C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\DirectoryContent\Content1\File.info`

I want to create a method to extract the repeated path:

**Result** `C:\Users\Me\FileFolder`

Is there a method to do this? Or how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to find all common folders, so the path that is shared from both, try this:

```
string path1 = @"C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\File1.info";
string path2 = @"C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\DirectoryContent\Content1\File.info";

string root1 = Path.GetPathRoot(path1);
string root2 = Path.GetPathRoot(path2);

if (root1.Equals(root2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    string[] folders1 = path1.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    string[] folders2 = path2.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    var commonFolders = folders1.TakeWhile((dir, index) => 
        folders2.Length > index &&
        dir.Equals(folders2[index], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    string commonFolderPath = string.Format("{0}{1}"
        , root1
        , Path.Combine(commonFolders.Skip(1).ToArray())); // Skip(1) skips root
    Console.Write(commonFolderPath);
}
```

Result: `C:\Users\Me\FileFolder`

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using `String.Split` method and `Enumerable.TakeWhile`

```
var part1 = path1.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
var part2 = path2.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

var commonParts = part1.TakeWhile((x,idx) => idx < part2.Length && part2[idx] == x);

if (commonParts.Any())
{
     var result = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), commonParts);
}
```

[`Fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U6IlHU)

Comment: Use the `Path` class, for example `Path.Combine` and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes using Path class is better, but Steve is right, Path.Combine doesn't add the first backslash, I'm not sure why though.it may be relevant with the colon in root folder (C:)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to use `Zip` with `TakeWhile` (suggested by Selman22).

```
string path1 = @"C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\File1.info";
string path2 = @"C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\DirectoryContent\Content1\File.info";
string[] part1 = path1.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string[] part2 = path2.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string[] commonParts = part1.Zip(part2, (p1, p2) => p1 == p2 ? p1 : null)
                            .TakeWhile(s => s != null)
                            .ToArray();
string commonPath = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), commonParts);
```

Slightly changed example of Selman22.

```
string path1 = @"C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\File1.info";
string path2 = @"C:\Users\Me\FileFolder\DirectoryContent\Content1\File.info";
string[] part1 = path1.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string[] part2 = path2.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string[] commonParts = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(part1.Length, part2.Length))
                                 .TakeWhile(i => part1[i] == part2[i])
                                 .Select(i => part1[i])
                                 .ToArray();
string commonPath = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), commonParts);
```